# How can I move an image from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using flutter to develop an application and want to be able to smoothly animate my image from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen after a certain delay.

How would I go about doing this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the image from the bottom to the top without moving anything else, then you should use a Stack widget with the image on top of everything and to move the image from the bottom to the top, you use an AlignmentTween from bottomCenter to topCenter. For a lot of similar animations, I suggest you take a look at this article by GeekyAnts: https://blog.geekyants.com/flutter-login-animation-ab3e6ed4bd19

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the image widget with a Transform widget and in the transform property you will use the named constructor "Matrix4.translationValues(double x, double y, double z)"
The with an animation you will replace the value of the Y axis